# left to right scrolling in landscape and addSubView

Tags: iphone, xcode, horizontal-scrolling

My comic book app is up and running but with a few things missing.

1) I want to have the images scroll from left to right, but I have the app automatically set itself up to landscape mode upon opening. Where to I tweak this part of the app? 
  (btw...It is doing left to right in portrait mode)

2) I have two of my images showing...where do I add the other 22 images in my code through addSubView?

```
// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
```

}
    [self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview

}

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do.  UIScrollView is for continuous scrolling -- if for example, you wanted the user to be able to view the right half of comic image 1 and the left half of comic image 2 at the same time.

If what you really want is for the images to be viewed more discretely (a "next page" / "previous page" paradigm), you might want to just have separate views and animate between them -- there would be no UIScrollView at all.

I can give you more specifics if you explain what behavior you actually want.

Comment: Its basically like those comic book apps you see in the app store. You swipe and then you go into the next page. So i'm having a hard time setting it up in that manner. any ideas?

Comment: check out "the terminator: death valley # 1 by dark horse and thats exactly what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

maybe these two links help you

http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html